# Intel Microcode propietary on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: microcode

I have a question about the Intel Microcode on Ubuntu 16.04. In my adicional drivers I have set it this:

[image]

("codigo abierto" means "open source", "privativo" means "propietary")

But searching on web, I found the Adicionals Drivers of other people look like this:

http://ubuntuhandbook.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/additional-drivers2.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ir1lT.png

If you see next to the name of Microcode (between brackets) it say "propietary". In my system it say "open source". Is there a way I can set like propietary and not the open source alternative? This is for testing something.